# Java 9 : cannot find symbol in test path

Tags: java, maven, java-9

In my (maven) project I have the following structure:

```
base.projectA
 |--shared     
     |--src
         |--main
             |--java
                 |--org.project.shared
                      |-- .....
                 |--module-info.java
         |--test
             |--java
                 |--org.project.shared
                      |-- TestBase.java
                      |-- TestDataContainer.java
 |--implementationClientA     
     |--src
         |--main
             |--java
                 |--org.project.implementationClientA
                      |-- .....
                 |--module-info.java
         |--test
             |--java
                 |--org.project.implementationClientA
                      |-- TestImplementationClientA.java
 |--implementationClientB     
     |--src
         |--main
             |--java
                 |--org.project.implementationClientB
                      |-- .....
                 |--module-info.java
         |--test
             |--java
                 |--org.project.implementationClientB
                      |-- TestImplementationClientB.java
```

*TestBase* and *TestDataContainer* are used in the test implementations *TestImplementationClientA* and *TestImplementationClientB*. A

> requires org.project.shared;

is added to both *module-info.java* of the client projects.

Nevertheless I get a "cannot find symbol" error for *TestBase* and *TestDataContainer* when compiling under Java 9.

Under Java 8 there was no problem (...and no *module-info.java*).

So what is the problem for Java 9 ?